# Three divs wider than screen without scrolling

Tags: html, css

I have page to maintain, which was developed very poorly by someone other. Every change for me is now a real ordeal.
Now page looks basically like this:

```
 ____________________
|                    |
|        body        |
|                    |
|                    |
|    width: 1000px   |
|                    |
|                    |
|____________________|
```

I would like to add some divs with links, so page should look like below:

```
 _______ ____________________ _______
| left  |                    | right |
| 400px |        body        | 400px |
| width |                    | width |
|_______|                    |_______|
        |    width: 1000px   |
        |                    |
        |                    |
        |____________________|
```

Body should be centered, and depends on window size, left and right divs should be shown entirely or just some parts of it.
I have searched web for similar problems and tried different solutions but they caused page crashes and page elements were in mess.

How can I easily add these divs?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/GSygt/

In the above fiddle, change the width of the center content to 1000px in your CSS. I've used 200px so that the result is visible inside jsfiddle output pane.

**HTML**

```
<html>
    <body>  
        <div class="center">

            This is my content!

            <div class="side left">LEFT</div>       
            <div class="side right">RIGHT</div>
        </div>
    </body>    
</html>
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;    
}
.center {
    position: relative;
    width: 200px;   /* change this to 1000px */
    background-color: #dfd;    
    margin: auto;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 600px;
}
.side {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;   
    top: 0;
    background-color: #ddd;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 200px;
}
.left {
    left: -400px;
}
.right {
    right: -400px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it works fine. But please tell me whether `.side` position can be easily changed to `fixed`, so that `.left` and `.right` will be visible while vertical scrolling?

Comment: @user1292810 You would have to change the following: `.left{ right: 50%; margin-right: 500px; }` and `.right{ left: 50%; margin-left: 500px; }` - http://jsfiddle.net/GSygt/1/

Comment: @MyHeadHurts Big thanks to you and techfoobar. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2):

So I'm assuming you can't change anything in your design, the only thing you can do is add the divs to the body. If that's the case here's how I'd do it: http://jsfiddle.net/joplomacedo/4p6nw/

1) First set the widths on your new divs.
2) Then float each other to their own side.
3) Add a negative margin to the side they're floated to equal to their width.
4) On the body, add a padding-left equal to the floated left div's width, then add a padding-right equal to to right floated div's width.

For this HTML...

```
<body>
   <div class="left-div"></div>
   <div class="right-div"></div>
</body>
```

...the CSS

```
body {
  width: 1000px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 400px;
}

.left-div {
  float: left;
  width: 400px;
  margin-left: -400px;
}

.right-div {
  float: right;
  width: 400px;
  margin-right: -400px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly use absolute positioning. (Although I would also recommend NOT using 1800px as a static width, I guess the two sidebars are for advertising, and I have had the same arguments with a marketing monkey before about page widths so I understand)

.center {position: absolute; top: 0; left: 50%; margin-left: -500px; display: block;}

then have left and right inside center but pull them out also with absolute positioning.

so for example

.right {position: absolute; top: 0; right: -400px; width: 400px;}

and the reverse for left.

Hope this helps, there will be a horizontal scrollbar, but the same applies to floated elements.

Answer (score -3):

I don't recommend to make your site to 1800px in width.

but you can follow the below structure :
 table with 3 td like

```
<table>
<tr>
<td id="first" valign=top> content </td>
<td id="middle" valign=top> content </td>
<td id="last" valign=top> content </td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and to disable scrolling add this to your stylesheet :

```
body{overflow-x:hidden;}
```

Comment: -1 Never ever use a table to create your design. This practice is frowned upon.

Comment: 2012 and suggesting table layouts? Have I entered the Twilight Zone?