# Divs with width 100% and float so one is off the side of the screen

Tags: css

I want to build a page that has a horizontal scroll. I want one div to fill the view window.

I set the width to 100% so it fills the window on any size screen but you can't then float the next div to the side of it.

Does anyone know a way to do this or a way to set the width based on the size of the screen.

I am using php and codeigniter with a bit of javascript.

Comment: you may need to set the width of the `body` and the `html` tags to 200% so that there is room for the second `div`

Answer (score 2):

Use your 100 % Div as a wraper and uses some divs inside that one to achive your designs. I Think you have to specify a width for the second div that you need to float and apply float, Hopes this will helps you

Comment: i cant specify a width for the second div as i need more then 2 and i need them all to fit the window

Comment: Do we can be specific about the number of divs that came inside the warpers ?

Comment: Hmm.. I think then specifying width as auto or nothing specify about width will help us.... Pls give it a try I am not sure about that fills 100% of our wrappers width

Answer (score 1):

You mean this http://jsbin.com/upoqec/2/edit#preview ?

HTML:

```
<body onload="resize()">
<div class="view" id="view">
</div>
<div class="follow">
    </div>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
body{overflow:auto; width:100%: height:100%;}
.view{width:100%; height:400px; float:left; border:2px solid black;}
.follow{position:absolute; left:100%; width:900px; height:400px; border:2px solid red; margin-left:20px;}​
```

Javascript:

```
function resize(){
  var winW = 630, winH = 460;
if (document.body && document.body.offsetWidth) {
 winW = document.body.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.body.offsetHeight;
}
if (document.compatMode=='CSS1Compat' &&
    document.documentElement &&
    document.documentElement.offsetWidth ) {
 winW = document.documentElement.offsetWidth;
 winH = document.documentElement.offsetHeight;
}
if (window.innerWidth && window.innerHeight) {
 winW = window.innerWidth;
 winH = window.innerHeight;
} 
document.getElementById("follow").style.width=winW.toString()+"px";
 document.getElementById("follow").style.height=winH.toString()+"px";
}
```

​

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer I posted as a reply to another similar question.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/11293897/921204

The changes needed are:

a) you don't need the 'left' div. So remove it.

b) do not specify `overflow-x: hidden;` to body since you want horizontal scrolling.

Also, change the dimensions of the center div as required. In you case, set it to `100%` width